# Difference between backtrace(backtrace_symbols) and bt in gdb

Tags: c, linux, function, gdb

backtrace_symbols() function in linux takes alot of time to translate addresses into array of strings but bt in gdb works fast.What is the difference between the functionality of backtrace_symbols() and bt in gdb?

Comment: Can you add to the question how you measured the difference in time?

Answer (score 0):

gdb reads symbols at startup time, and uses the data structures it builds from those symbols in subsequent command invocations, such as bt. If gdb were to repeat symbol reads for each invocation of bt, that would make bt slower, possibly comparable in speed to backtrace_symbols().